# Please suggest infrastructure for passing data between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, protobuf-net

I'm using P/invoke to interoperate between C# and C++ in [this project](http://bitbucket.org/nesteruk/typografix). I'd like to pass data structures that are symmetrically defined. What's the best infrastructure to use? Could protocol buffers be useful here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use C++/CLI since you can use the same header files / definition files in both worlds. One of the main goals for developing C++ CLI was to fill the gap between the managed and the unamanaged world. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliintro01.aspx) article gives you even more advantages.

In the MSDN there is [a nice description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) how C++cli works and how you can use it.

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150477/c-and-c-interoperability-p-invoke-vs-c-cli/3150521#3150521)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, you may want to look into using COM.  Define .NET classes that are COM visible and have the InterfaceType ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual, and decorate each parameter with the MarshalAs(UnmanagedType) attribute, then the C++ app can marshal objects that can be passed between managed and unmanaged code.

The "Symmetrical definition" is handled because the interface is defined in COM, plus COM gives you a little more error handling and visibility into what is going on than straight P/Invoke.